# Zurb Foundation responsive table does not work?

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am trying to build responsive table  with foundation code.   I downloaded Responsive table file from Foundation.

I used inline CSS and JS .  But , the  responsive table does not work . So my questions are :

1 ) Can I build responsive table with Foundation's CSS and JS file alone or should I download whole Foundation 6 ? Do I need whole Foundation 6 file to build responsive table ?

2)  The downloaded JS folder contains 9 files . Should I upload each of them manually  to my server ?

3 ) My website does not have JQUERY file. Should I upload jquery.min.js to my server ? Should I include this code 
 in my website ?
  Can I build responsive table without   jquery code  ?

Comment: Are you using the whole of Foundation just for a responsive table? Can you post some code?

Comment: @hapless, did you ever get a working solution to the responsive table?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you do not need other files than the css and js.
2. Not sure what files you downloaded, you only need the one called “responsive-tables.js”.
3. To get Zurb responsive to work you need to use jQuery 2 (script is not compatible with the newest version - jQuery 3 ). You can include the file or link to a cdn file.

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).load(updateTables);` replace `$(window).on('load', updateTables);`